# Can I install and manage MySQL, PostgreSQL and MongoDB in one pc?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm currently working with MySQL and PostgreSQL but I want to give mongodb a try. I don't if it possible or not , moreover I'm scared to loose my phpmyadmin and pgadmin's data.
By the way I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Yes, you can install all of them in the same PC. But I wouldn't do it in a production system

Comment: Docker can make this easy

Comment: @DanielA.White To the extent that Docker is easy, which it is not to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use both MySQL and MongoDB on the same PC. I have used MySQL and MongoDB